# Tail events application

Tags: probability-theory

Define $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}= \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \sigma ( X_k, k \geq n)$.

Is the event $\{ \exists j \geq 1, X_j = x\}$ in $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$?

First notice that $\{ \exists j \geq 1, X_j = x\} = \{ \bigcap_{j \geq 1} X_j = x \}.$ If we consider the complementary of the event we get:
$\bigcup_{j\geq 1}\{ X_j \neq x \}$. Now the only thing I don't manage to show is that $\{ X_j \neq x \}$ is (or is not) in $\mathcal{B}_{\infty}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not true in general. For example suppose $0<P(X_1=x)<1$, $X_i$'s are indepemdent and $X_i$ is a continuous r.v. for $i>1$. Then, by Kolomogorov's $0-1$ law your event has probability $0$ or $1$. But $P(X_i=x)=0$ for all $i >1$. This implies that $P(X_1=x)$ is $0$, or $1$, a contradiction.